# Как в IntelliJ IDEA дебажить стримы Java 8?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, отладка, java-stream, java-8

Как в IntelliJ IDEA дебажить стримы Java 8? Все промежуточные вызовы ленивые и исполняются во время терминальной операции, так что, делать перенос методов на отдельные строки бессмысленно. Я пока не смог заставить идею показать элементы стрима на каком-то шаге, отличного от начального и конечного. `System.out.println` расставлять - как-то непрофессионально, есть другие способы из коробки?

Comment: Отлаживайте по исходникам Java 8. Есть же исходники в JDK?

Comment: используйте Stream.peek() в промежуточных точках.

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с версии 2017.3 в IDEA встроен Stream Debugger.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Активировать его можно, когда отладчик остановился на стриме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Stream Debugger визуализирует каждый шаг стрима, наглядно показывая фильтрацию и трансформацию элементов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Думаю самое лучшее это ставить Breakpoint с условиями. Можно условия промежуточной функции ставить.

1. Создаете Breakpoint
2. ставите условия на переменную или переменные
3. дебаг остановится в указанном месте при указанных условиях

Примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Специально для этого есть операция `peek(...)`

Она не терминальная, можно использовать в стриме многократно.

В качестве параметра принимает `Consumer`, поэтому для отладки можно передать печать в консоль.